# Combine Neo4j, Spring Data and Neo4j Predicates

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I found `org.neo4j.helpers.Predicate` interface. I use Neo4j and Spring Data.
I have a repository like this:

```
public interface RelationRepository extends GraphRepository<Relation> {
}
```

But when I want to call `relationRepository.findAll(new MyPredicate())` it does not work. There is no method created for consuming predicates. Is there any way to combine it all together?

Answer (score 1):

You can use QueryDSL predicates with QueryDslRepository.

see this section: http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-data-neo4j/3.3.0.M1/reference/html/#reference_programming-model_repositories

or the tests:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/blob/master/spring-data-neo4j/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/neo4j/repository/CypherDslRepositoryTests.java

Comment: Yes, but this approach is a little bit ugly IMO. And you have to specify start  node, when I don't want to do it (I see no point in it)